# Regex: how to capture a group starting with a matched set of characters

Tags: php, regex

Here is a string of characters that I would like to split into an array:

```
35g walnut halves A handful of thyme leaves 200g portobello mushrooms 200g white mushrooms 200g chifferini pasta 100g Petit Brebis sheep's cheese 40g honey
```

I would like to use `preg_split` to extract the individual ingredients from the string. An individual ingredients starts with:

- a quantity defined by digits plus the character `g`
- a sequence a characters such as `A handful`

So far, I have this regex pattern `([0-9]+g|A handful)` which correctly finds the breaks in the string, but doesn't include the entire ingredient description. I need the capturing group to include the rest of the characters until the next match.

In order to get the array return, I use this PHP:

`preg_split("/([0-9]+g|A handful)/", $ingredients_str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`

The desired output is:

```
[
  0 => 35g walnut halves
  1 => A handful of thyme leaves
  2 => 200g portobello mushrooms
  etc..
]
```

See [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/D6pRpk/1)

Comment: Please update your question with desired output.

Comment: If you need to *extract*, use `preg_match_all`, not `preg_split`

Comment: What if it includes something like `2 eggs`.

Comment: And this will never be accurate unless you know all of the possibilities.  Is it `2 handfuls` or `Two handfuls` is there the possibility of `A pinch` etc.?  Will there never be `40mg` or `1kg` etc...?

Comment: There are many more possibilities but want to learn for myself how to use regex :)

Comment: Delimiters would help, maybe inspect the string and see if there are hidden newlines or tabs that you could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` to extract all the descriptions:

```php
preg_match_all('~(?:\d+g|A handful).*?(?=\s*(?:\d+g|A handful|$))~s', $str, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a2X0kL/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\d+g|A handful)` - 1+ digits followed with `g` or `A handful`
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*(?:\d+g|A handful|$))` - up to a location in string that is immediately followed with 0+ whitespaces followed with either 1+ digits and `g`, or `A handful` or end of string.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/MLnKk):

```php
$re = '/(?:[0-9]+g|A handful).*?(?=\s*(?:[0-9]+g|A handful|$))/s';
$str = '35g walnut halves A handful of thyme leaves 200g portobello mushrooms 200g white mushrooms 200g chifferini pasta 100g Petit Brebis sheep\'s cheese 40g honey';
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
   print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 35g walnut halves
    [1] => A handful of thyme leaves
    [2] => 200g portobello mushrooms
    [3] => 200g white mushrooms
    [4] => 200g chifferini pasta
    [5] => 100g Petit Brebis sheep's cheese
    [6] => 40g honey
)
```

A `preg_split` solution may look like

```php
$re = '/(?!^)\b(?=[0-9]+g|A handful)/';
$str = '35g walnut halves A handful of thyme leaves 200g portobello mushrooms 200g white mushrooms 200g chifferini pasta 100g Petit Brebis sheep\'s cheese 40g honey';
print_r(preg_split($re, $str));
```

See the [demo online](https://3v4l.org/KUTTZ). Here,

- `(?!^)` - matches a location that is not at the start of string
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=[0-9]+g|A handful)` - a location that is immediately followed with 1+ digits and then `g` or `A handful` substring.

Comment: great many thanks - what difference is there, if any, between the `preg_split` and the `preg_match_all` solution? (on an academic level) To me it seems `preg_split` at least has a shorter regex pattern, so perhaps easier to work with or grow?

Comment: @greener If there is arbitrary text at the start of the text, `preg_match_all` will fetch the matches without that initial text. If your input is all descriptions and nothing else, yes, `preg_split` will do.